# Is this sentence correct, are there any better ways to phrase this sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I'm trying to say that many people are doing the same thing -- when I did it, I was viewed differently. But the sentence sounds a bit dull, I'd like other ways to phrase this or suggestions.

> While I told my speech, I had come to the realization that I was being
>   observed differently than others who were  doing the same thing I was.

Comment: While speaking I realized that I was being observed differently from the others.

Comment: It is always best to wait a few hours before awarding somebody's answer. Some American users might still be asleep at this hour!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the exact scenario you are going through but this may help you in the right direction:

"All of us"/"The whole class" "chose"/"were assigned" "similar topics"/"the same topic". While I was delivering my speech, I realized that I was "viewed"/"observed" differently from the others.

Answer (score 0):

You may say:

While I was giving my speech, I realised that  I was being observed by the audience in a different way with respect to other speakers.

Answer (score 0):

While making my speech, I realized that I was being observed differently than the others.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

I realized that audience were observing me differently while delivering the my speech.

Answer (score 0):

> While delivering my speech, I realized that the audience was perceiving me differently to the other speakers.